# how to break down this file with regex in php

Tags: php, regex

I have a big inventory file have multi lines of entry all with the same format:

```
<item>   xxxxx item details   </item>
```

I am thinking of breaking this down by preg_split with a regex expression. so i can get an array of lines each is a separate item entry.

new to regex. would like to get some help on writing the right regex expression to define the pattern of   xxxx

something like:  `^(<item>)\w*(</item>)`

but my test always generates errors.

thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following pattern should do it:

`<item>\s*([^<])</item>`

You'll need to use preg_match_all to get all of the items if there are more than one:

`preg_match_all('%<item>\s*([^<]+)</item>%', $db, $items);`

$items after this will contain an array like

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "<item> 123456 qwerty </item>"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "<item>123 whatsoever</item>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(14) "123456 qwerty "
    [1]=>
    string(14) "123 whatsoever"
  }
}
```

so $item[1] will contain an array of what was inside the brackets in the pattern.

What we do here: first we don't limit the record to be at the beginning of a line with ^. Then we skip whitespaces after  tag with \s*. Then we define a group of characters that we want as an output with (...). Inside it we define what characters we understand as item info with [...]: any characters within this group will fit the pattern. ^ in this groups makes it negative, so [^<] will fit any character that isn't a <, which will effectively get us to the closing  tag.
If you want to also split the item info into several parts (like item ID, description) you can alter this pattern to somewhat like:

`<item>\s*(\d+)\s*([^<]+)</item>`

Then the result will be:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(28) "<item> 123456 qwerty </item>"
    [1]=>
    string(27) "<item>123 whatsoever</item>"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "123456"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(7) "qwerty "
    [1]=>
    string(10) "whatsoever"
  }
}
```

$items[1] contains what is inside the first brackets, $items[2] - inside second group, and so on if you add more.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have the extra parens.  To detect a string of 0+ non-space characters and get them in a group at the start of a string:

```
^(\w*)
```

If you want at least one char in your xxx string, use + instead:

```
^(\w+)
```

If you want to get the first group of characters which is not a space:

```
^([^ ]+)
```

And if you want the first group of characters which is not whitespace:

```
^(\S+)
```

As a quick note: Use + for 1 or more of something, use * for 0 or more of something.

Comment: Guess I missed the fact that you're inside xml tags.  In that case, you need to recognize those too, so the other answer should work for you.  The carrot at the beginning of your regex is matching the start of the string, so it will only work if your pattern is at the very beginning of a string